# Is there a way to replace the PlantUmlModel tag with the PlantUml script?

Tags: api, metadata, documentation, plantuml, docfx

Is there a way to replace the PlantUmlModel tag with the PlantUml script when the project is compiled? I do use Docfx to generate documentation

```
   ///  <summary>
    ///<PlantUmlModel type = "IAnimal" / >
    ///</ summary >
    public interface IAnimal
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Name of Animal. for example pishi
        ///</summary>
        string Name { get; }
    }
```

````
<![CDATA[
```plantuml
interface IAnimal {
Name: string
}
````

]]>